# Django Filter ForeignKey relationships in get_queryset

Tags: django

I wonder what to do here.
 So I have an EmailAddress class which has a ForeignKey relationship to my User class

```
class EmailAddress(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(allauth_app_settings.USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('user'))
email = models.EmailField(unique=app_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL,
                          verbose_name=_('e-mail address'))
```

I also have a UserProfile class which has a OneToOneField relationship with the mentioned User like so:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
attribute= models.CharField("attr", max_length=150, blank=False)
```

Now in admin.py I want to filter the Users so that the current user who is logged in to admintool can only see emails from users who share some attribute. The catch is that the attribute is saved in UserProfile and I need to get there through the email.

Basically I don't know how to access the 'attribute' which is in the UserProfile. I understand that I want to filter users by taking the email finding the user that this email belongs to and then compare his 'attribute' to the user who send the request to decide whether to show it to him or not.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
user = [User whos email is in the list]
qs = [the queryset]
[and then]
return qs.filter([filter so the user attribute = the request.user attribute])
```

Im using allauth btw. in case you wonder what

```
 allauth_app_settings.USER_Model
```

stands for.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the double-underscore syntax to follow the relationships.

```
qs.filter(user__userprofile__attribute=request.user.attribute)
```

Comment: And how do I get hold of User instance? I tried `user = User.objects.filter(email=request.email)[0]` or `UserProfile.objects.filter(user__id=request.id):` but  it wont work.

Comment: You have it already in `request.user`. You don't need to get anything else. The code I show above can be the entire contents of the `get_queryset()` method.

Comment: Well thats kind of my problem because if I try to do it like so `def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(EmailConfirmationAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs.filter(user__userprofile__attribute=request.user.profile.attribute)
        return qs` im getting this error message: `Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: created, email_address, email_address_id, id, key, sent`

Comment: That's not a problem with getting the current user, that's a problem with querying the model. And *that's* because you didn't give all the relevant information in your questions: these are fields from a completely different model (EmailConfirmation maybe?) which is evidently the one associated with this admin class. Since that model apparently has a field called `email_address` which is a ForeignKey to EmailAddress, you should add `email_address__` to the beginning of the filter value I gave above.

Comment: Indeed I got a little bit confused and forgot to mention that, in the end it did work with `(email_address__user__profile__attribute=request.user.profile.attribute)` and I learned how the lookups work. Thanks for the patience.